# pgfplot error bar in foreground

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to get the error-bar of the lower y-bar ontop of the stacked bar. Which command can I use to get the error bar to the foreground? Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{scrreprt}
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usepackage{filecontents}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{filecontents}{A3Met.dat}
    X   Y   Z   Y_error Z_error Y_label Z_label
    {ctr.}  0.26        0.407   0.1 0.1 0.39    0.61
    {Probe} 0.3778  0.314   0.1 0.1 0.55    0.45
    \end{filecontents}

    \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \begin{axis}[
          bar width=1cm,
          x=2cm,
          y=4cm,
          ytick={0,0.2,0.4,...,1},
          enlarge x limits={abs=1cm},
          symbolic x coords={{ctr.},{Probe},},
          ymin=0,
          ymax=1.05,
          ylabel={Aufnahme in rel. Einheiten},
          xticklabel style={text width=2cm, align=center},
          xtick=data,
          axis x line*=bottom,
          axis y line=left,
          yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%} ,
          nodes near coords,
         visualization depends on=abs(y)/y*(0.15+\thisrow{Y_error}) \as \myshift,
         every node near coord/.append style={yshift=-transformdirectiony(\myshift),inner sep=1pt},
         legend style={at={(1.8,0.5)},anchor=east, legend cell align=left, 
         reverse legend},
              ]
            \addplot +[
    ybar stacked,
     color=black,
            fill=gray!50,
             mark=none,
             point meta=explicit symbolic,
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=south},
            error bars/.cd,
              y dir=both,
              y explicit,
    ] table
    [y=Y, x=X,  y error=Y_error, meta=Y_label] {A3Met.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Ph}
    \addplot +[
    ybar stacked,
     color=black,
            fill=white,
             mark=none,
             point meta=explicit symbolic,
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor=south},
            error bars/.cd,
              y dir=both,
              y explicit
    ] table [y=Z, x=X,  y error=Z_error, meta=Z_label]{A3Met.dat};    
    \addlegendentry{Tr}
     \end{axis} 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `fill=white` for the second plot, use `fill opacity=0,text opacity=1`. This only works for a white page, but that is most cases I suppose.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{A3Met.dat}
X   Y   Z   Y_error Z_error Y_label Z_label
{ctr.}  0.26        0.407   0.1 0.1 0.39    0.61
{Probe} 0.3778  0.314   0.1 0.1 0.55    0.45
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \begin{axis}[
      bar width=1cm,
      x=2cm,
      y=4cm,
      ytick={0,0.2,0.4,...,1},
      enlarge x limits={abs=1cm},
      symbolic x coords={{ctr.},{Probe},},
      ymin=0,
      ymax=1.05,
      ylabel={Aufnahme in rel. Einheiten},
      xticklabel style={text width=2cm, align=center},
      xtick=data,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%} ,
      nodes near coords,
     visualization depends on=abs(y)/y*(0.15+\thisrow{Y_error}) \as \myshift,
     every node near coord/.append style={yshift=-transformdirectiony(\myshift),inner sep=1pt},
     legend style={at={(1.8,0.5)},anchor=east, legend cell align=left, 
     reverse legend},
          ]
        \addplot +[
ybar stacked,
 color=black,
        fill=gray!50,
         mark=none,
         point meta=explicit symbolic,
        every node near coord/.append style={anchor=south},
        error bars/.cd,
          y dir=both,
          y explicit,
] table
[y=Y, x=X,  y error=Y_error, meta=Y_label] {A3Met.dat};
\addlegendentry{Ph}
\addplot +[
ybar stacked,
 color=black,
        fill opacity=0,text opacity=1,
         mark=none,
         point meta=explicit symbolic,
        every node near coord/.append style={anchor=south},
        error bars/.cd,
          y dir=both,
          y explicit
] table [y=Z, x=X,  y error=Z_error, meta=Z_label]{A3Met.dat};    
\addlegendentry{Tr}
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```